# PHP/MySQL: Hashing common data

Tags: php, mysql, hash, sha

I am looking at my current database set up and it consists of a silly amount of user full home addresses in about 7 different tables, all with a varying degree of inconsistent data (due to the way people can type their postcode with/without spaces, for example).

The application in question is not yet live - not far off full completion but still not live, so any change now would be much easier than say 6 months down the line when there's a ridiculous amount of data in the tables.

Would it be worth my while to spend a few hours refactoring the code/database that handles user home addresses and instead of inserting the full one every time, using a hashing algorithm?
This would give us much greater consistency and could obviously be set up in a way that users could share an address hash and so therefore we could even search them by address much easier.

We currently use this method with storing user agents - hash the UA String and store it in its own separate table alongside a Medium Text column for the actual UA string to go, then instead we store the UA Hash in tables that require it (see below), and use SHA1. However, what options are available to me in terms of non-collision based hashing, but you've also seen to execute in the quickest possible time in a small-medium scale production environment?

[image: UA String Hash Table]

This means that the two obvious ones, MD5/SHA1 are 100% not happening, and I don't really work with hashes bigger than that unfortunately. 
For the record, for the password encryption I use `password_hash` so don't freak out!

Obviously a user's home address is much more important than a user agent string which is why I'm asking what you'd recommend.

Thanks

Comment: "non-collision based hashing" - What do you mean? The hashes of two different strings should never be equal?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel You are correct, they shouldn't but there are cases with MD5/SHA1 where that isn't true. [Wiki - More info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_attack). See also [MD5 Collision Example](http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/) and [SHA1 Collision](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/02/23/google_first_sha1_collision/)

Comment: I'm not an expert, but AFAIK those functions only exist for predifined sets of strings. But why don't you just use the primary key as reference?

Comment: Can't you just create an address table with an Autoincrement key and use this key anywhere you need an address?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I'm trying to future proof the application as much as possible to save a rewrite in months/years to come, especially bits like the Database, and who knows what it's like then. For all I know (although unlikely) 2 people's addresses could end up being the same, then I've got an issue. I was also thinking about using the AI Key, but I want something that can be done quicker on-the-fly without the extra pulling and searching that it would take. That way I can just search for the hash instead of every address column. (CC @NigelRen)

Comment: It's possible that 2 people may be on the database with the same address, if not sharing a house, one could have moved out and new person sets up details before old one has updated theirs.

Comment: @NigelRen that is true - which is why we'd search the database for the new hash, and if we don't find it we just input the new address, generate a new hash and update the hash on the table that uses it. That way all old orders are also still correct (old card processing data linked to old addresses for example). The whole point of the hashing is to make searching & storing the information in other tables much easier :-)

Comment: @DomLip You can still use a hash for a fast search. But when you find an address with the same hash you need to check if it's really the same address.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel That's why I'm asking about known collisions & the speed trade off. Because you shouldn't have to check its the same address when you're searching through hashes of the actual data itself. Say you've got the following hash (SHA1): **6bef63a52809ee535b9d8246b7f70c68f1f66205** , which is actually the hash of the following string **Room 100, Building, City Centre, Liverpool, Merseyside, L1 7AA, United Kingdom**. You should be able to trust that the hash is just the hash of that address only, and no other possible string.

Comment: All i can think of is to use compression (zip) and use it instead of a hash with a prefix index.

Comment: But a hash slows you down -- possibly by an extra disk hit!  I suggest you simply accept that two _different_ entities can have the _same_ address, and reach _beyond_ the address to disambiguate.  No hashing.

Comment: You are correct - but the amount of MySQL queries we are already running is complex so I was trying to avoid having to find the ID. In saying that though, we've moved away from the hashing and just took the miniscule MySQL hit (we are already connected over SSL which is a bit of an extra overhead). In the long term it's just easier for us to do as is, as we are also processing card details (via Stripe) so can't afford for any info to go missing, messed up, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you wondering, I went with SHA256.

I didn't realise there's actually a function in openssl to benchmark hashing algorithms, which can be used like: `openssl speed alg1 alg2 alg3 etc`

Looking at the 64/256 byte results in the table below, although obviously it doesn't perform as quick as MD5/SHA1, I've decided its still quick enough for the production anyway.

I thought I'd post this and let anyone who doesn't know about `openssl speed` have a go.

```
[root@prod-use1a ec2-user]# openssl speed md5 sha1 sha256 sha512
Doing md5 for 3s on 16 size blocks: 9785239 md5's in 3.00s
Doing md5 for 3s on 64 size blocks: 7076501 md5's in 2.99s
Doing md5 for 3s on 256 size blocks: 3832312 md5's in 3.00s
Doing md5 for 3s on 1024 size blocks: 1363911 md5's in 3.00s
Doing md5 for 3s on 8192 size blocks: 194888 md5's in 3.00s
Doing sha1 for 3s on 16 size blocks: 10839355 sha1's in 3.00s
Doing sha1 for 3s on 64 size blocks: 7479305 sha1's in 2.99s
Doing sha1 for 3s on 256 size blocks: 4024302 sha1's in 3.00s
Doing sha1 for 3s on 1024 size blocks: 1478185 sha1's in 3.00s
Doing sha1 for 3s on 8192 size blocks: 227631 sha1's in 3.00s
Doing sha256 for 3s on 16 size blocks: 7984178 sha256's in 3.00s
Doing sha256 for 3s on 64 size blocks: 4370920 sha256's in 3.00s
Doing sha256 for 3s on 256 size blocks: 1904856 sha256's in 3.00s
Doing sha256 for 3s on 1024 size blocks: 589307 sha256's in 3.00s
Doing sha256 for 3s on 8192 size blocks: 77639 sha256's in 2.99s
Doing sha512 for 3s on 16 size blocks: 6481869 sha512's in 3.00s
Doing sha512 for 3s on 64 size blocks: 6479426 sha512's in 3.00s
Doing sha512 for 3s on 256 size blocks: 2425680 sha512's in 3.00s
Doing sha512 for 3s on 1024 size blocks: 869702 sha512's in 3.00s
Doing sha512 for 3s on 8192 size blocks: 120660 sha512's in 3.00s


The 'numbers' are in 1000s of bytes per second processed.
type             16 bytes     64 bytes    256 bytes   1024 bytes   8192 bytes
md5              52187.94k   151470.26k   327023.96k   465548.29k   532174.17k
sha1             57809.89k   160092.15k   343407.10k   504553.81k   621584.38k
sha256           42582.28k    93246.29k   162547.71k   201150.12k   212715.28k
sha512           34569.97k   138227.75k   206991.36k   296858.28k   329482.24k
[root@prod-use1a ec2-user]#
```